# How do I check if one list contains 2 elements of another list with more elements?

Tags: c#, list, contains

I am working on a application in C# and I am stuck at something.

I have 2 list with strings. List1 has 4 elements and List2 has 6 elements.
Now I need check if 2 elements from List1 exists in List2, no matter the order.

I have been stuck with this and I don't know how to code it.
Does someone have any suggestions?

```
List<string> List1 = new List<string>();
    List1.Add("blue");
    List1.Add("red");
    List1.Add("orange");
    List1.Add("aqua");

List<string> List2 = new List<string>();
    List1.Add("orange");
    List1.Add("aqua");
    List1.Add("blue");
    List1.Add("red");
    List1.Add("purple");
    List1.Add("pink");

if () //List2 contains 2 elements of list1 no matter the order
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-5.0) Method. Try like:

```
 if (list1.Intersect(list2).Count()>=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(List2.Intersect(List1).Count == 2){}
```